# Cómo agregar nuevos registros a una tabla a partir de un archivo .log

Tags: php

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en PHP y los datos a insertar en la base de datos están en un archivo .log (puro texto) con separacion por comas.

¿Cómo se podrían insertar todos esos datos en varias variables para insertarlas posteriormente en la base de datos, borrar el log y a un tiempo dado realizar el proceso nuevamente?

Comment: Hola @William. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te comento que seguimos otra dinámica en el sitio. No es un reemplazo de Google. En cambio, esperamos que hayas investigado, y muestres el código que estás intentando, dónde estás teniendo problemas, las estructuras de tus datos y tablas, y el resultado esperado. Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP tiene una función nativa para parsear CSV, [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php). El único detalle es que te toca a ti decirle cuál es el separador. En este caso ya lo sabes asi que no es problema.

Sería así:

```
$handle = fopen("archivo.log", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    var_dump($data);
}
fclose($handle);
```

en este caso le digo que lea el CSV usando separador coma, y que no use un límite de largo sino que considere que cada fila está separada sólo por saltos de línea.

Verás que en cada iteración del bucle, la variable `$data` es un array con los datos de la fila. En vez de poner cada dato en una variable, usarías `$array[0]...$array[n]` para aludir a cada campo.

Comment: gracias colega con tu explicacion y ejemplo y los ejemplos del link a php.net resolvi, solo me queda seguir con la problematica que es puro algoritmo